# error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@types/jest'

Tags: typescript, github-actions

Today when I am building the react app using command in GitHub Actions:

```
export NODE_ENV=production && tsc && vite build --mode production
```

shows error:

```
+ vite 4.3.9

Done in 19.5s

> rd-component@0.1.111 build /home/runner/work/rd-component/rd-component
> export NODE_ENV=production && tsc && vite build --mode production

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for '@types/jest'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library '@types/jest' specified in compilerOptions
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

in the local machine, the `pnpm run build` works fine. Am I missing something when running this command in GitHub Actions? this is the `package.json` about `@types/jest'`:

```
"@types/jest": "^29.5.2"
```

this is the github Actions script:

```
name: rd-component-publish

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - name: Build React App
        run: |
          git config --global url."https://github".insteadOf ssh://git@github
          npm install -g pnpm 
          pnpm install
          pnpm run build
        env:
          CI: false
      - uses: JS-DevTools/npm-publish@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue solved by removing the `typeRoots` property in `tsconfig.json` (I had set it to `"typeRoots": ["./.typings", "./node_modules/@types"]` which it wasn't happy with)